# Rails-style template helpers in Velocity

Tags: templates, velocity, html-helper, view-helpers

I need to add a number of really complex dynamic HTML structures to my Velocity template. If I were to attempt to write these directly in the template, it would be an absolute mess.

Let me explain what I'm trying to do... let's say, on my website, a user can post comments. Rather than writing all the complex dynamic HTML structure that goes into the comments table and the posting form, I would like to be able to do this in my template:

```
<div>
    // call to a method that generates the comments table
</div>
<div>
    // call to a method that generates the comments form
</div>
```

In Ruby On Rails, there are things called [helpers](http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/show/49-using-helper-methods-in-ruby-on-rails) that allow you, from the templates, to call, basically, a method that returns a dynamically-generated chunk of HTML, to be embedded in the template right where you call it. The nice thing about helpers is that you only spend CPU on the ones you use. With the `VelocityContext.put()` method, it seems like I have to generate everything I need in advance. This is a problem because I will ultimately have some 50 different helpers, and I need the non-programmer web designer to be able to swap them in and out at will.

So I am asking,

1. Can I do something like this with Velocity?
2. If not, can I do something like this with some other template engine?
3. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I submitted this without using my brain. All you gotta do is create a Helper class:

```
public class HtmlHelper {

    public String getSomeHtml() {
        return "<p>badgers</p>";
    }

}
```

Then add an instance to the context:

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
HtmlHelper helper = new HtmlHelper();
context.put("helper", helper);
```

Then in the template:

```
<div>
    $helper.getSomeHtml()
</div>
```

Finally, [dance the merengue with a dog](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nc9xq-TVyHI) in celebration.

Comment: And you can use VelocityTools to have your HtmlHelper automatically instantiated and dropped into the context when you reference $helper in your template.

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider (or are you using) [Velocity Tools](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/) already? I tend to see them as pretty analogous to Rails helpers, and definitely the best place to keep view-specific logic. Depending on the exact implementation you could look at wiring in your helper as a custom tool, and then let the Tools framework seamlessly manage the instantiation etc. If your helper is just a POJO you may find it already works as a tool without any changes.

Alternatively, if your helpers are only building HTML structure and don't have any complex Java dependencies, maybe you could just create them as [macros](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.6.4/user-guide.html#Velocimacros)?

Comment: And with VelocityTools 2, the tools aren't even instantiated until you use them.